# How to update user info in firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I've currently building a leaderboard where someone can update their score once logged into my app.

Here is the form where the user can update their score:

```
<section class="card register">
    <form name="myform" ng-submit="update()" novalidate>
        <div class="textintro">
            <h1>Update Score</h1>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="score" placeholder="Score" ng-model="user.score" ng-required="true">
            <p class="error validationerror" ng-show="myform.score.$invalid && myform.score.$touched">Must be a valid score</p>
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-disabled="myform.$invalid">Update Score</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

And this is the function i've created to update the user score, got some help off firebase docs:

```
update:function(user){
    auth.$updateProfile({
        name: "Jane Q. User",
        score: "15"
    }).then(function() {
        $location.path('/leaderboard');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        $rootScope.message = error.message;
    });
}
```

But getting this error:

> TypeError: auth.$updateProfile is not a function

Full JS file:

```
myApp.factory('Authentication',
    ['$rootScope', '$location', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseAuth',
        function($rootScope, $location, $firebaseObject, $firebaseAuth) {

            var ref = firebase.database().ref();
            var auth = $firebaseAuth();
            var myObject;

            auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(authUser) {
                if(authUser) {
                    var userRef = ref.child('users').child(authUser.uid);
                    var userObj = $firebaseObject(userRef);
                    $rootScope.currentUser = userObj;
                } else {
                    $rootScope.currentUser = '';
                }
            });

            myObject = {
                login: function(user) {
                    auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                        user.email,
                        user.password
                    ).then(function(user) {
                        $location.path('/leaderboard');
                    }).catch(function(error) {
                        $rootScope.message = error.message;
                    }); //signInWithEmailAndPassword
                }, //login

                logout: function() {
                    return auth.$signOut();
                }, //logout

                requireAuth: function() {
                    return auth.$requireSignIn();
                }, //require Authentication

                register: function(user) {
                    auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        user.email,
                        user.password
                    ).then(function(regUser) {
                        var regRef = ref.child('users')
                            .child(regUser.uid).set({
                                date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                                regUser: regUser.uid,
                                name: user.name,
                                score: user.score,
                                email: user.email
                            }); //userinfo
                        myObject.login(user);
                    }).catch(function(error) {
                        $rootScope.message = error.message;
                    }); //createUserWithEmailAndPassword
                }, //register

                update:function(user){
                    var user = auth().currentUser;
                    user.updateProfile({
                        displayName: "Jane Q. User",
                        photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
                    }).then(function() {
                        // Update successful.
                    }).catch(function(error) {
                        // An error happened.
                    });

                }

            }; //return


            return myObject;



        }]); //factory
```

Comment: This does not look like the code described in [the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile).

Comment: It's because im using angular1, I will post the full JS file, rest works fine e.g login, logout & register

Comment: Have now updated main question with full JS file

Comment: If auth is a reverence to your factory than this simply a typo. The function in your factory is called update and not updateProfile.